# error outputting file with python 3.0

Tags: python, io

I am not sure why I am receiving this error. Everything in my program seems to be working perfectly. the program is basically a simple administration system to store username and password accounts.

the error i get is, ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

the program successfully writes the first account, but the other accounts do not get stored in the .txt file

here is my code where i am getting the error

```
if savedata == 'y': 
print ("\nData Successfuly Saved!")
filehandle = open(filename, "r+")

    for username, password in store_data.items():
        print(username, ":",password)
        password = password.replace("\n","")
        filehandle.write(username) # it says this line is my error
        filehandle.write(":") 
        filehandle.write(password)
        filehandle.write("\n")
        filehandle.close()  

   else:
 ("Exiting Application Terminal...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should fix matters:

```
if savedata == 'y': 
    print ("\nData Successfully Saved!")

    with open(filename, "w") as filehandle:
        for username, password in store_data.items():
            print(username, ":", password)
            password = password.replace("\n","")
            filehandle.write("{}:{}\n".format(username, password))
else:
    print("Exiting Application Terminal...")
```

You were closing the file after each iteration, as you only opened it once, this is why only one entry was saved.

It is also safer to use Python's `with` construct which will automatically take care of closing the file for you.

If you wish to append to an existing file, use `"a"` as the mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file for writing:

```
filehandle = open(filename, "w")
```